# How to pass content while calling app.router.navigate() in Framework7?

Tags: frameworks, html-framework-7

Here is the dynamic page route:

```
{
         path: '/news/',
         name:'news',
         content: '<div class="page newPage"><div class="page-content"><div class="block"><p> This page created dynamically</p></div></div></div>',

         }
```

I am calling the dynamic page like this:

```
app.router.navigate({name:'news'});
```

My question is how to change the content of that page by passing some parameters, something like this:

```
app.router.navigate({name:'news', new-content:'<div>Hi new content</div>'});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to append your content or any variable to ( params ) before you navigate

```
app.router.params["PageMode"] = "new";
app.views.main.router.navigate({name:'newbill'});
```

then you can receive it when page init

```
  $(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="newbill"]', function (page) {

  console.log(app.router.params.PageMode); 

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The content to a page are passed in through the routes for example :

```
routes = [
    {
       path: '/news/:id/:content',
       url: 'somepage.html'
    }
]
```

so when you sending the parameters to the route you will simply do like :

```
var id = parseInt(someNewsID);
var  content = 'Lorem ipsum ...........';
app.mainView.router.navigate('/news/' + id + '/' + content);
```

making sure you are separating your variables with a slash as in the path

Retrieving the values will be as simple as :

```
var myID = app.mainView.router.currentRoute.params.id;
var myContent = app.mainView.router.currentRoute.params.content;
```

and then you can manipulate your dom using JavaScript or JQuery to load the values and use them